# what is a good way of creating a back button to different 'coming from' pages

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have two different pages, from which a user can click on a 'details' link and go to the details page.

On the details page, I have a 'back' button, which leads the user to the originating page, being one of the two original pages of course.

There is also one extra issue: in one of the return links, I must specify an extra anonymous object.

my view code right now is:

```
@{
    MvcHtmlString backLink = null;
    if (Model.ReturnPage == MatchResultReturnPage.Search)
    {
        backLink = Html.ActionLink("GoBack", "Search", new {search = true});
    }
    else
    {
        backLink = Html.ActionLink("GoBack", "Dashboard");
    }
}
```

In the controller I now look in the `url.referrer` if it contains '*dashboard*', then I set the `Model.ReturnPage` to '*Dashboard*'.

Is there a cleaner way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the `ReturnLink` as a property on your model and set it inside the controller, which will alleviate the need for you to put that logic in the view.

Comment: I like the idea about creating the backlink in the controller, but how can i access the `Html` (`HtmlHelper`) from the controller?

Comment: Use `Url.Action("ActionName", "ControllerName", new { parameter = param });` in the controller instead of the `HtmlHelper`

Comment: Hi, this gives me a string with the path only, is that correct? the `Html.ActionLink` gives me an entire A link . I tried using the `Html.ActionLink` with the path from the controller, but i do have to provide an actionname for the `Html.ActionLink`. Does that mean that i have to create the A link myself?

Comment: @Michel Yeah that's correct, just use the `a` tag instead of `Html.ActionLink` in your view to create it yourself. Annoyingly, there's no overload for `ActionLink` that takes a full URL.

Answer (score 1):

There are certainly cleaner ways, but as your code is currently, it is very easy to understand what you are trying to do.

I would say keep it as is and simply put a #region wrapper around it and hide it when you don't need to work with it:

```
#region get referrer page
MvcHtmlString backLink = null;
if (Model.ReturnPage == MatchResultReturnPage.Search)
{
    backLink = Html.ActionLink("GoBack", "Search", new {search = true});
}
else
{
    backLink = Html.ActionLink("GoBack", "Dashboard");
}
#region
```

The only thing I would suggest is to have this check in the Controller, rather than the view and simply putting the result of your check either in model property, or in the ViewBag.

To gain access to Helpers in your controller, do the following:

```
var URL = new UrlHelper(this.Request.RequestContext).Action("MyAction", "MyController", new { id = 123 });
```

Comment: I like the idea about creating the backlink in the controller, but how can i access the `Html` (`HtmlHelper`) from the controller?

Comment: Like such : var URL = new UrlHelper(this.Request.RequestContext).Action("MyAction", "MyController", new { id = 123 });

Answer (score 0):

you should probably implement the Back button entirely in JavaScript. 
using the [history object](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/obj_history.asp)

```
<a href=”javascript:history.back()”> [Back]</a>
```

Comment: Unless the page opened in a new tab/window.

Comment: It will probably miss the  `new {search = true}` part when this was not previously in the page.